# is there any way that we can save a file in flutter web like in android cache?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I want to download a zip file and save it in a temporary folder then extract it in that. Is there any way we can do it in flutter web?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences package support web 
check it

Comment: @AliNabel i want to save a zip file..

Answer (score 0):

You can check this package: https://pub.dev/packages/archive
The new versions are web supported.

Comment: have you read the question? its not about working with archives!

Comment: this is not working on flutter web and there is no example on the web